# How do you check/start SQL browser service under linux?

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-20.04

I have just installed MS-SQL 2019 under Ubuntu 20.04 (the first time I have installed this Db under linux). I opened up port 1433 and can connect to it via the server IP address with Management studio from my windows laptop.

However I think that the server browser service isn't running as even though I have opened up port 1434 I can't browse to the database.  I also suspect that the service may be disabled by default. I have down a lot of googling but can't seem to find linux related instructions for the browser service.

How can I check that the browser service is/isn't running?  And if not, what steps do I need to take in order to get it running under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly **SQL Server Browser Service** is **not supported on Linux**.

If you visit the [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2019 on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2019?view=sql-server-ver15) and scroll down to the [Unsupported features & services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2019?view=sql-server-ver15#Unsupported) section you will find the following services listed as unsupporrted:

> ```
> Services  SQL Server Browser       <<== Unsupported!
>           SQL Server R services1
>           StreamInsight
>           Analysis Services
>           Reporting Services
>           Data Quality Services
>           Master Data Services
> ```

Comment: That's what I get for assuming that I get the full product under Linux (and for not reading *all* of the documentation!).  It's a good thing that this was only a test project.